# Single Sign-on in Rails 3 without any extra work on the users part?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, single-sign-on

I have an app built in rails 3 that is currently using authlogic for authentication. I have another site built in php where I would be able to access my rails 3 app from within the php app, something like in an iframe.

What I am wondering is if it is possible for me to allow users to login to my php app and when they navigate to my rails 3 app in the iframe they would be automatically signed in to my rails 3 app?

I have looked into using OmniAuth, but all of the examples I have seen involve a third party service such as twitter that it authenticates against and the user is required to click a series of buttons to make the authentication relationship. What I want is for the php app to essentially send a uid and secret or something of that nature when it tries to access the rails 3 app in the iframe and use that to either create a user or sign in an existing user. Does this even sound plausible? Is there a simpler way to have single sign-on without authenticating through a third party service as well?

Answer (score 1):

Use OmniAuth with the Identity strategy:

https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-identity

Comment: Yep, be sure to checkout the [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/304-omniauth-identity) too!

Comment: I checked out omniauth-identity and the related railscast and it seems to me that it is just what you would use if you want to give the user the option to login through email and password. I don't understand how it fits my scenario though. My two apps are on different domains and when I log into the php app I want to be automatically logged in to the rails app. How does omniauth-identity help that?

Comment: From what I understand, you want to authenticate a user in your Rails application. And you want to do this through a PHP application. One way to do this would be to use OmniAuth Identity. Each user of the Rails application would have to authenticate themselves through OmniAuth Identity. Each user has to have an entry in the Identity table (part of the sign-up process).

Comment: Typically, each entry consists of an email and associated encrypted password. Then a user could authenticate themselves by specifying their email and password (part of the sign-in process). Once authentication completes, OmniAuth Identity sends the user to a specified callback URL. This URL could point to the SessionController new member function. There you could sign in the user and redirect them to the home page of your Rails app. I recommend you implement the Railscast example and then try to sign-up a user and then sign-in a user through your PHP application.